# Easy way to get pixel data from string with font

Tags: c++, fonts

Say I make a 2D array in RAM. Are there any libraries that make it easy to draw *directly* to my array (as opposed to drawing the text to the screen or a render target in VRAM)?

Even if I could at least get the pixel data of a single character using a specified font would be nice.

I'm relatively new to C++ though so it needs to be simple..

If the specified font doesn't use/store bitmap then it would have to convert it for me.

Comment: Try FreeType - http://www.freetype.org/

Comment: Freetype is not 'simple' to use.

Answer (score 2):

[FreeType](http://www.freetype.org/) is a cross-platform open-source library under BSD-like license, renders a dozen of font types (including TrueType and OpenType), and works on all major operating systems.

As an alternative, you could use OS-specific APIs to render text into memory bitmap (which is accessed directly like an array). There is no difference between rendering to screen and rendering to memory bitmap, you just need to create an off-screen bitmap image and select it as destination. In Windows, use `CreateDIBSection` function; in OS X, create `NSBitmapImageRep` object or use `CGBitmapContextCreate` function (which is also available in iOS). This is quite an easy task (under 100 lines of code) in all of them, creating 2-4 OS-specific files may be easier than adopting FreeType (especially if you already know those APIs).